# Search not working in special characters in magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

search not working Product names with special characters like **semiautomático** in magento 2

or any way to Ignoring special characters during catalog search?

how to solved this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default search is MySQL-based. So can be impacted by DB character set options.

However is it possible you can look in the database for semiautomático value?

There is a possibility the accent character has been saved as an HTML entity which is why you are not getting a match.

In which case you may have to look at this feature https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/search-synonyms.html